# ImageView ScaleType is Not Working - why?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am working on a design. And there is a LinearLayout for using weights. Inside of theese layouts, there are ImageViews. ImageViews showing pictures off course but every image has different aspect ratio. Then i want to use ImageView scaleType property for image's cover to all surface of ImageView. But nothing changed. In Android Studio design preview it's working but when we install the app simulator or real device; nothing change. You can find XML code below;

Waiting your answers; thank you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="12"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/tarot" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/sorusor" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/tarot" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/sorusor" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/magicBallBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/magicballbtn" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/burcbuton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/burcbtn" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/anaekranbutontasarim"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/btntasarim1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/baseline_star_black_24"

            android:text="Kredi Al"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Kalan Kredi: 100"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLight"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

and please go through below url
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType
 if you need any further clarification.

Comment: I try every option of them; centerCrop, fitXY, center.. everything. Nothing change on image. @Sajith

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `ScaleType=fitXY` and `ScaleType=center` are quite different.

`fitXY` is going to have our fixed height and then it’s going to scale our image filling the width. You're keeping the aspect ratio of the image while keeping the height to a certain size but letting the width change accordingly, so we are still able to control the size of the image (kind of) and maintaining the aspect ratio at the same time.

`center` just centers the image without scaling it.  If you add `adjustViewBounds=true` in it, you're going to keep the aspect ratio of the ImageView with adjustViewBounds the size of the ImageView (not the image) keeps the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Thanks for answer but here my problem is all of scaletype options not working. I try every options but never seen any change. @underwood

Comment: @EmreErol I think the problem is from the size of you image `match_parent`. Try to take a fixed size and normally all scaleType will work

Comment: I try it nothing change. @underwood

Answer (score 0):

remove **android:adjustViewBounds** then try